# Doc string from parent class to children class functions

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I have a `Django==2.2.3` app with `djangorestframework==3.9.4` and `django-rest-swagger==2.2.0`. I wanted to have a single source of truth (for data validation as well as api-docs) for my api endpoints. I have a JSON that looks something like this

```
{
    "get": {
        "query_param1" : {
            "type": "string",
            "required": "false",
            "message": "what does it do/what is it for?"
        },
        "query_param2" : {...},
        "responseMessages": {
            "code: 401": "Not authenticated",
            "code: 403": "Insufficient rights to call this procedure"
        }
    },
    "delete": {
        "query_param1" : {...},
        "query_param2" : {...},
        "responseMessages": {...},
    },
    "put": {...},
    "post": {...},
}
```

I created a json schema from this and the validation is working.

This json is converted to a yaml string which is used by `django-rest-swagger`. How it uses the yaml is, you need to put the yaml in the doc strings. But I don't want to go and write the same thing for every thing. There will be many endpoints and writing the same thing for all those endpoints doesn't feel right.

So I figured if I make a base class and just send the json to that base class, it can create all the doc strings for me, using the json and put it dynamically to the required functions. I now face a blocker and it says.

**AttributeError: attribute '__ doc __' of 'method' objects is not writable**

This is how my class looks like

```
class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    schema = json.load(schema_path)
    self.get.__doc__ = convertToYaml(schema['get'])
    **ERROR HERE: AttributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'method' objects is not writable**


class Child(Parent)
  def get(self):
    JsonResponse({message: "Hi! I work fine" })
```

TLDR:

**Error obtained**: AttributeError: attribute __ doc __ of method objects is not writable

**Question**: How to change a children's class function's docstring from a parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define it in the parent's `__new__` method.

Here is a simple example of how you can override it.

```
class Parent(object):
    """ This is the Parent"""
    def __new__(cls):
        cls.__init__.__doc__ = cls.__bases__[0].__doc__
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print('hello')


class Child(Parent):
    """ This is the Child """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

test = Child()

print(test.__init__.__doc__)
```

In your example it would be this:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        schema = json.load(schema_path)
        cls.get.__doc__ = convertToYaml(schema['get'])
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

Comment: You have changed the doc string of the class instead of the method. And thank you because it works even for methods. The only problem is dynamically assigned doc strings don't seem to work for my case.

Comment: But this does answer the asked question. So I will select this as the right answer if you can go ahead and change your code to change the function's docstring instead of the class'

Comment: It's been changed. Sorry, I didn't catch that you were changing the doc string of the method but it should work for both methods and classes.